# Transferring authentication from ASP site to JSP

Tags: asp.net, jsp, authentication, transfer

I have an asp.net site which uses the same database as another JSP site. The JSP site does some reporting and asp site is used for data entry. What I need is once a user is logged in to asp.net site and clicks on one of those common id's, I want to take them to the jsp site to show the report without having them to sign in again. The username and password for the jsp site is exactly the same as asp since they use the same user table. The JSP site is 3-4 years old and I am not at all experienced in it. So if anyone can help me out here.

Here is the Response Header and Request Header for the login into JSP site:

```
**Response Headers**
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Wed, 05 Dec 2012 15:20:49 GMT
Location    http://www.something.something.htm?action=0
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie  JSESSIONID=523454ADB2B7C19D29BD68DB55D30146
Host    www.something.something.com
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Referer http://www.something.login.htm
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0
Request Headers From Upload Stream
Content-Length  41
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Header contains only username and password with mode=0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When someone clicks on the link for jsp site... I would send user to an intermediare page... Which has a form with user name and password as hidden field. Set the action of the form to jsp's form(which is used for login).  And auto submit form using javascript.

Comment: So I add a new page to my asp site which will post to the login page of the jsp site? How ill that take the user to the report page as I need to pass the ID from the asp to jsp as well. Can you post a small example please.

Comment: Have your form submit with a additional hidden field, which will have a indication that login was successfull. Read that value on a jsp page and redirect user to the reports page. Reading request variable and resirecting user should be easy in jsp.